# What digit is the most frequent?

Tags: c

Basically, user should type in a number, and program should return most frenquent digit in that number. Problem is, when I run the program, and enter a number, it always returns 2.  I know that the code is way too long, sorry. Could you help me locate the problem? Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long int ulli;
int maxi(int n,int j,int d,int t,int c,int p,int ses,int s,int o,int de)
{
    int big;
    big=n;
    if(j>big)
    big=j;
    if(d>big)
    big=d;
    if(t>big)
    big=t;
    if(c>big)
    big=c;
    if(p>big)
    big=p;
    if(ses>big)
    big=ses;
    if(s>big)
    big=s;
    if(o>big)
    big=o;
    if(de>big)
    big=de;
    return big;
}
int main()
{
    int i,de,o,s,ses,p,c,t,d,j,n,l,k;
    ulli xM;
    ulli x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=x;i<=0;i/10)
    {
        k=0;
        for(l=0;l<10;l++){
            if(i%10==l && k==0)
            n++;
            if(i%10==l && k==1)
            j++;
            if(i%10==l && k==2)
            d++;
            if(i%10==l && k==3)
            t++;
            if(i%10==l && k==4)
            c++;
            if(i%10==l && k==5)
            p++;
            if(i%10==l && k==6)
            ses++;
            if(i%10==l && k==7)
            s++;
            if(i%10==l && k==8)
            o++;
            if(i%10==l && k==9)
            de++;
            k++;
            }
     }
    xM=maxi(n,j,d,t,c,p,ses,s,o,de);
    if(xM==n)
        printf("0");
    else if(xM==j)
        printf("1");
    else if(xM==d)
        printf("2");
    else if(xM==t)
        printf("3");
    else if(xM==c)
        printf("4");
    else if(xM==p)
        printf("5");
    else if(xM==ses)
        printf("6");
    else if(xM==s)
        printf("7");
    else if(xM=o)
        printf("8");
    else if(xM=de)
        printf("9");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The first problem is that your code is an unreadable mess because you are using nonsense one-letter variable names.

Comment: If the user enters "001", what do you want to see as the most frequent digit? Your code, and the current answers, assume that "1" is the correct output, but based on the problem description, I would actually expect "0". There's also an assumption that numbers consist of only digits. Is that assumption correct, or can numbers also include a minus sign, a thousands separator, a decimal separator, perhaps anything else?

Answer (score 6):

For start: no one of your variables is initialized:

```
 int i,de,o,s,ses,p,c,t,d,j,n,l,k;
```

So the first part of your code...

```
    for(l=0;l<10;l++){
        if(i%10==l && k==0)
        n++;
        if(i%10==l && k==1)
        j++;
        if(i%10==l && k==2)
        d++;
        if(i%10==l && k==3)
        t++;
        if(i%10==l && k==4)
        c++;
        if(i%10==l && k==5)
        p++;
        if(i%10==l && k==6)
        ses++;
        if(i%10==l && k==7)
        s++;
        if(i%10==l && k==8)
        o++;
        if(i%10==l && k==9)
        de++;
        k++;
        }
 }
```

Adds 1 to a variable with an undefined initial value, which may or may not be 0.

To initialize all them you can do:

```
 int i,de,o,s,ses,p,c,t,d,j,n,l,k;
 i=de=o=s=ses=p=c=t=d=j=n=l=k=0;
```

But... then you use `i` en this `for()` loop...

```
for(i=x;i<=0;i/10)
```

Although it's initialized to the value of `x` (after having converted `x` to an integer value) this will run forever, as `i/10` is always `0` if `i` is `0` (`i` is `int`, so it's an integer division what your are doing), and eventually, this will happen no matter big is `i` at the beginning.

I think you may want to rethink your logic about this code. My suggestion: convert the number to a string using `sprintf` and count how many times the character `'0'` is found in the string, then character `'1'`, etc.

Comment: There's no need for converting to a string. `%` and `/` work perfectly in C.

Comment: Yep, but I was thinking about a simple and understable way of doing this, as how you would do it with a pen and paper: you would treat the number not as a number, but as a sequence of digits (characters). Even for some problems it's the only way to go: for instance, to check if a positive integer number of an arbitrary length is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 2):

You are tackling the problem the wrong way — unless you've not been taught about arrays, yet.  Whenever you find yourself writing almost the same code out multiple times, you need to learn to step back and think about a better way of organizing the solution.  (Remember, programmers only need 3 numbers: 0, 1, many.)

In this case, an array is ideal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long int ulli;

static int maxi(int values[10])
{
    int big = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] > values[big])
            big = i;
    }
    return big;
}

int main(void)
{
    int values[10] = { 0 };     // Zero counts
    ulli x;

    if (scanf("%llu", &x) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Analyzing: %llu\n", x);

    do
    {
        int d = x % 10;
        values[d]++;
        x /= 10;
    } while (x > 0);

    int n = maxi(values);

    printf("Digit %d appears %d time%s\n", n, values[n], (values[n] != 1) ? "s" : "");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs:

```
$ min <<< 314159265389
Analyzing: 314159265389
Digit 1 appears 2 times
$ min <<< 3141592653893
Analyzing: 3141592653893
Digit 3 appears 3 times
$ min <<< 31415926538937
Analyzing: 31415926538937
Digit 3 appears 3 times
$ min <<< 314159265389373
Analyzing: 314159265389373
Digit 3 appears 4 times
$ min <<< 3141592653893730
Analyzing: 3141592653893730
Digit 3 appears 4 times
$
```

The `<<<` notation is a `bash` trick for feeding input to a program from standard input.  It is a [Here String](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), rather like a one-line 'here' document.

Answer (score 1):

You are using uninitialized variables, you need to initialize every variables before uses them.

```
int i=0,de=0,o=0,s=0 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

For a bit of variety here is a totally different way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf, scanf */

typedef unsigned long long ulli;

int main()
{
    ulli x;
    int high = 0;
    int num = scanf("%lld", &x);
    int arr[10] = {0};
    int index = 0;
    int i;

    if(num == 1) {
        while(x) {
            arr[x % 10]++;
            x /= 10;
        }

        /* find largest index */
        for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            if(arr[i] > high) {
                index = i;
                high = arr[i];
            }
        }
        printf("Most frequent digit: %d, count: %d\n", index, high);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

COMMENT UPDATE

Why if(num == 1)

scanf returns the number of variables in format list filled, so it is a way to check successful 'decoding'.  So it is basically a check that a numeric value was read into the x variable.

x % 10 means what is the remainder when you divide the number by ten.  This will be the units digit.

eg  123 % 10 -> 3

So we take the unit digit on each iteration in the while loop.

arr[] is an array of ten items - the items are the decimal values 0 - 10.

So if the number was 123 then arr[x % 10]++ would increment arr[3] by 1.

To iterate from left to right over t6he number 123 we need to then 'remove' the former units digit to then examine the digit to the right.

eg

int x = 123;

x % 10; // will be 3

x /= 10;  //x now = 12

x % 10;  -> 2

x /= 10; x now = 1

Comment: can you please explain what does this part of code do                'if(num == 1) {
            while(x) {
            arr[x % 10]++;
            x /= 10;
        }'

Comment: What happens if the user enters `0` as the number?  I am not a fan of the `do ... while` loop, but I think this is a case where the `while (x)` loop should become a `do { ... } while (x != 0);` loop.

Comment: @user3104311 quite a bit to explain - I will add as comment update to code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I did think about that but laziness prevailed.  Agreed for real usage.